# how to create multi select auto complete combobox?

Tags: javascript, html

In my case I want to implement a multi-select auto-complete combobox using HTML, JavaScript, and JSP.

Is there anybody who knows how to implement this?

This will be similar to the text field shown in StackOverflow while adding multiple tags to any question.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend an [Ajax-driven auto-complete JavaScript combo-box](http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxCombo/index.shtml), especially if you have a large set of data to query.

Otherwise, various javascript libraries (like [Yahoo UI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/autocomplete/ac_combobox.html)) do provide this kind of combo-box.

For instance, this [combo-box](http://lovcombo.extjs.eu/) based on [ExtJS checkbox](http://lovcombo.extjs.eu/) does offer a multi-select feature.

Comment: Yep - this is not a not a multi-select solution.

I've tried jquery.multiselect.js, fcbkcomplete, and the tokenizing autocomplete text entry ... and I'm getting tired.

Those are the top jquery choices.
Each comes with its own "gotchas"
Most are:
CSS ... don't lend themselves to complex forms, 
browser issues ... broken visually or broken functionality in IE
and 
user-interface issues (supports backspace? delete, arrows, etc.?) and just bugs (can't take slashes, can fall into endless loops, etc).

There doesn't appear to be a really solid, easily styled jquery version of such a beast.